# ASP.NET Get Gridview Label Text in Javascript

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have muliple rows in my grid for hours. I have a common label for the same `lblFromTime`.
I need to get the label text bound in each row from javascript.
Could someone offer me a solution?

I tried the following code but it doesn't return the text.

```
var gvRowCount = ('<%= gvTimeSlots.Rows.Count%>');
for (i = 0; i <= gvRowCount; i++) 
{
    var fromTime = document.getElementById('ContentHead_MainContent_gvTimeSlots_lblFromTime_i');
    alert(fromTime.value);
}
```

Comment: Isn't the code for getElementById be like this: `document.getElementById('ContentHead_MainContent_gvTimeSlots_lblFromTime_' + i)`  ?

Comment: Yeah, but the alert displays null though there are values in all the rows.

Comment: thats is id of ur label in side gridview ContentHead_MainContent_gvTimeSlots_lblFromTime_i

Comment: lblFromTime is inside the grid. Right now it has 3 rows of data. But the alert displays only null.

Comment: if its id is lblfromtime..than why u passing...
ContentHead_MainContent_gvTimeSlots_lblFromTime_i is it ur label rendering with that name

Comment: Yes. I took this ID from View Source window in the browser.

Comment: ASP.NET Label controls are converted to SPAN tag. SPAN tags don't have values. Try `fromTime.innerText` or `fromTime.innerHTML`

Comment: @th1rdey3, both innerText and inneHTML aren't displaying values at all.

Comment: you are starting i from 0, please check whether the first lblFromTime/span id starts from zero or not.

Comment: Yep, it does start from 0 only.

Comment: then your for loop should be `for (i = 0; i < gvRowCount; i++)`. i think the last alert is displaying null.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out a sample like this

**ASPX Code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="check">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("iso") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
```

the `Gridview` generated the following HTML -

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="gv" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">check</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="gv_ctl02_lbl">ab</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="gv_ctl03_lbl">ab</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="gv_ctl04_lbl">ab</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

as you can see for my case the span id started from 2.

so i tried the following javascript

```
for(i=2;i<5;i++) console.log(document.getElementById('gv_ctl0'+i+'_lbl').innerHTML);
```

and the result was

```
ab
ab
ab
```

I tried it out in chrome and firefox(firebug). both are working fine.

Comment: I have a master page. Hence the naming convention ContentHead_MainContent_gvTimeSlots_lblFromTime.

Comment: try your code with `console.log` instead of `alert`. see if the null reference is shown only when `i` is equal to `gvRowCount`

Comment: console.log doesn't work on older version of IE. which browser are you using?

Comment: `console` and `log` both should be small letter. Also check your browsers security level to see if javascript can run or not.